# Service worker Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

Tags: laravel, service-worker, sw-precache, sw-toolbox

would you please tell me what i did wrong with my service worker installation, i have those errors appear in chrome console (see the image-1).

```
The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.                          service-worker.js:1

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT          https://harampress.com/post/45/service-worker.js
```

i use Laravel framework in backend if that could help

just to know that my service-worker.js is in the root of the website, works fine on home page no errors on chrome console, but the moment i try to navigate to a post for example, those two errors appears (see image-2).

knowing that i use sw-precache and sw-toolbox, i generate the service worker useing sw-precache with gulp.

[image-1](https://harampress.com/uploads/files/shares/service%20worker.png)

[image-2](https://harampress.com/uploads/files/shares/serivce-worker-errors.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the solutions [here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1001#issuecomment-258487310) on github discussion

*the message from the discussion in github that actually answered to my problem :*

---

What **@wanderview** means is that when you do

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
```

The actual requesting URL is the sw.js located in the root

but when you do

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
```

This is actually a Relative URL so what you actually request might be `/post/blah/sw.js` and your server might treat it as 404 and do some redirect.

---

Comment: Please include the answer here on SO